# Is it possible to edit and save files in a ZIP archive with Xarchiver without extracting them?

Tags: linux, xfce, zip, archive, file-roller

I know it's possible with GNOME archive manager (File Roller). When editing a text file inside a ZIP archive, pressing the *Save* button of the text editor will pop-up a window from the archive manager saying: "Would you like to update the archive?"

Is it possible with Xarchiver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not exactly the same as described.

[Xarchiver](http://xarchiver.sourceforge.net/) will first copy the text file to the preferred temp directory (default: /tmp), and user will have to make changes and save the changes made temporarily first. To actually update the text file, user has to do the following:

1. Go to **Action > Add** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
2. Click **Selection** tab, and then **select** the text file in the temp directory (default: /tmp/xa-*/filename.txt)--This step may not require user action, as the sidebar might already show the "Recent" column and the corresponding text file may be selected already
3. Click **Options** tab, and then **fill the checkbox** "Freshen and replace" to only include the text file with changes from the temp directory--This step may need to do only once
4. Finally, click **Add** to finish.

Following above steps will update the text file without extracting in Xarchiver. The steps are less intuitive and somewhat troublesome, but that is just the way a lightweight archive manager handles such user action.

If user wanted the similar behaviour to edit and save files as [File Roller](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/) does, the closest alternative would be Engrampa (screenshot below).

[image: Edit and save text file in Engrampa]

[Engrampa](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa) is an archive manager for MATE, which is also the fork of File Roller. In recent years, File Roller has been replaced by Engrampa in MATE and Xfce.